# How to call a method of one .cs class in another .cs class in C# WPF application

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple **CRUD WPF application** using C#. All I want to do is to import an already defined method of one class into another which is defined in a different file of same application.

I have applied several approaches but none has worked.

```
namespace Demo__Project
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }

    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-EKH75FM;Initial Catalog=DCS;Integrated Security=True");
    
    public void LoadData()
    {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM DemoDatabase.dbo.UserData";
        SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sqlcon.Open();

        SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(sdr);
        sqlcon.Close();

        Datagrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

    }
```

The method `LoadData` is the one which I want to call into another class of a different .cs file. Please help me achieve this task.

Comment: a.) Get that method out of the window class it does not belong there. Put it somewhere else (a different class) that does nothing else then handling database tasks. b.) let the method then return the datatable instead of directly adding it to some control. Instantiate that new class and use that method from everywhere you need.

Comment: I've created a class in a separate file and defined the same method in that class. Also, instantiated the class in main window where I have to call the method but still it gives me error of `LoadData` does not exist in the current context

Comment: you called MyLovelyNewClass.LoadData()? Because the method is in a different class now. Showing relevant code might help.

Comment: [https://github.com/hasankh17/CRUD_app ] Please visit this Link. The file `class.cs` contains the class in which the method `LoadData` is defined. All I want is to call that method into my `deleteoperation.xaml.cs` file. Ive already instantiated the method though.